# Unit test default Assertion method?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, assertions

I am doing Assertion by doing comparision of dto's and model object.Like this :-

```
Assert.AreEqual(_oCustomer.FKCustomerId, actual.FKCustomerId);
Assert.AreEqual(_oCustomer.Name,actual.Name);
Assert.AreEqual(_oCustomer.Description,actual.Description);
```

But I want,instead of doing Assertion for every property in each test method can we have any default/automatic functionality for it ? Can anyone guide me on this ?

Comment: What have you tried? Try typing "C# object equality" in your favorite web search engine. You can do `Assert.AreEqual(_oCustomer, actual)` if you have the proper equality comparer.

Answer (score 1):

Without polluting your model and/or namespaces by overriding `Equals()` to compare models with DTOs, you can simply create a method that performs the comparison and call into it in each test. Now you can still assert on a property-by-property basis (so you can see exactly which one is breaking the test), but you'll only ever have to change it in one place.

```
public static class ModelDtoComparer
{
    public static void AssertAreEqual(Model model, Dto dto)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(model.FKCustomerId, dto.FKCustomerId);
        Assert.AreEqual(model.Name, dto.Name);
        Assert.AreEqual(model.Description, dto.Description);
        // etc.
    }
}
```

***comment response***
To do this with lists, where `modelList` should match `dtoList` item-for-item:

```
Assert.AreEqual(modelList.Length, dtoList.Length);

for (var i = 0; i < modelList.Length; i++)
{
    ModelDtoComparer.AssertAreEqual(modelList[i], dtoList[i]);
}
```

Comment: Jay how can i use this with list of objects(dto list and model list) ?

Comment: @Pawan Are the lists expected to be equivalent, item-for-item? So, the 10th item in the DTO list should equal the 10th item in the model list?

Comment: yes,i am mocking the objects so it will return the same list which we will want or which will pass into the return method.

Comment: Thanks @Jay......Jay i have some more stuffs to do.And in which i want to know the best example of unit test of method returning void.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection to write some kind of comparer. This will compare Level1 properies of given two objects (public properties only):

```
static void AssertAreEqual<T1, T2>(T1 instance1, T2 instance2) {
  var properties1 = typeof(T1).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetProperty);
  var properties2 = typeof(T2).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetProperty);

  var properties = from p1 in properties1 
                   join p2 in properties2  on
                     p1.Name equals p2.Name
                   select p1.Name;
  foreach (var propertyName in properties) {
    var value1 = properties1.Where(p => p.Name == propertyName).First().GetGetMethod().Invoke(instance1, null);
    var value2 = properties2.Where(p => p.Name == propertyName).First().GetGetMethod().Invoke(instance2, null);
    Assert.AreEqual(value1, value2);
  }
}

public class PersonDto {
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  public int FieldFoo { get; set; }
  public int Dto { get; set; }
}

public class PersonModel {
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  public int FieldFoo { get; set; }
  public int Model { get; set; }
}

var p1 = new PersonDto { LastName = "Joe" };
var p2 = new PersonModel { LastName = "Joe" };
AssertAreEqual(p1, p2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection if you want, here's a generic method you can use to compare any two objects you want no matter what type they are :

```
public void CompareMyObjects(object object1, object object2)
{
    var type1Fields = object1.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.GetProperty);
    var type2Fields = object2.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.GetProperty);

    var propsInCommon = type1Fields.Join(type2Fields, t1 => t1.Name, t2 => t2.Name, (t1, t2) => new { frstGetter = t1.GetGetMethod(), scndGetter = t2.GetGetMethod() });

    foreach (var prop in propsInCommon)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(prop.frstGetter.Invoke(object1, null), prop.scndGetter.Invoke(object2, null));
    }
}
```

you can use the method as follows :

```
CompareMyObjects(actualCustomer, _oCustomer);
CompareMyObjects(actualAccount, _account);
```

I hope that helps.